# Input text typing lags too much because of big number of events

Tags: javascript, events, input, types, lag

I'm doing an app , and I have this page with 200 input text boxes. Almoust all of them have an event on ready/input , here is an example

```
function callpVol41l() {
  plan_vol_sc('plan_hrs_41l', 'prod_41n', 'plan_vol_41l');
}

$(document).
  on('ready input', callpVol41l).
  on('input', '#plan_hrs_41l,#prod_41n,#plan_vol_41l', callpVol41l);
```

My problem is due this high number of input texts , when I type in any of them , it has a small lag. There is any solution ? ( Is not only with google chrome , I know that issue , it has a bit lag even with IE.. less than chrome anyway.)

Comment: What does `plan_vol_sc` do? Have you checked with the debugger tools (e.g. Performance analysis) where the lag comes from?

Comment: plan_vol_sc is a function that gets the value from the input text with id=prod_41n and divide it with the value from the input text with id plan_hrs_41l and writes the result into the input text with id plan_vol_41l , and no I didn't checked with the debugger tools..

Comment: jQuery is very inefficient. If the inputs are in a form, then you can use POJS and property access rather than building jQuery objects and calls to its methods. Provide a minimal working example.

Answer (score 0):

You are attaching everything directly to the document. Perhaps just select the input differently?

Add a class to your input and add an `onchange` event to the input.

```
<input class="something">
```

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $input = $('input.something');
  $input.on('change', function(){
    var myValue = $(this).val(); // get value
    callpVol41l(myValue); // run the function you want to happen.
  });
}
```

Comment: Ok but my problem is that I have to do that less or more.. 150 times.. And I had to attach it directly to the document because I had an issue with the dynamic autofill inputs.. the function was not fireing without.. That's why I had to do like that..